# c++ undefined behavior of a reference to a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, reference, push-back

Please see my code. I have a base class "System" and a derived class "AdvancedSystem". When accessing the base class reference the output is undefined and random, and i have no idea why. Accessing the derived class gives me expected output. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class System {
public:
    System() :
        someValue(12345)
    {}
 
    int someValue;
};

class AdvancedSystem : public System {
public:
    AdvancedSystem()
    {}
};

class Strategies {
public:
    Strategies(System& system) :
        system(system)
    {}

    System& system;
};

class Test {
public:
    Test() :
        system(),
        strategies(system)
    {}

    AdvancedSystem system;
    Strategies strategies;
};

class Tests {
public:
    void createTests() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i) {
            values.emplace_back();
        }
    }

    std::vector<Test> values;
};

int main() {
    Tests tests;
    tests.createTests();
    std::cout << tests.values[0].system.someValue << "\n"; // outputs expected value of 12345
    std::cout << tests.values[0].strategies.system.someValue << "\n"; // outputs random number
}
```

Comment: When `values` grows and gets reallocated, all your references become invalid.

Comment: Cool thanks. Whats the solution here? Shared pointers?

Comment: That's for sharing objects, so it could be good. (A reference member is almost always a mistake.)

Comment: `std::list` is worse performance-wise most of the time, but sometimes this doesnt matter and it helps with stable iterators (a list does not reallocate)

Comment: Defining copy and move c-tors/operators for `Test` and `Strategies` should also do the trick. Handle reallocation of the reference there. Didn't test it, though.

Comment: Perhaps `Strategies` should not reference `System` at all. Since all accesses to both are through `Test`, the latter knows where the relevant `System` object is, and pass it to `Strategies` methods.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking the same, instead of storing the "System" object as reference inside "Strategies" i could use it as argument when calling some method inside Strategies from test.

Answer (score 3):

Using references as class members is usually a sign of bad design. In your case it's even worse because you creat self refenced objects. In such senarios you mustn't rely on [**rule 0**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), but rather [**rule 3**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) or [**rule 5**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Upon each `emplace_back` on your vector, the vector gets reallocated and values are moved from old allocation to new allocation. Because you follow rule 0, copy/move is handled by auto generated `default` code; therefore the `system` reference is **bitwise copied** and since the original self-referenced object is destructed, you end up with a **dangling reference** refering to nowhere(random memory location). This is a versatile case of **UB**. You can postpone the disaster by preallocating the vector via `vector::reserve` method, but that only hides the actual problem and buys time for catastrophe.

The ultimate solution is to revise your design to prevent dangling reference problem under any circumstances. You need define either copy or move constructor properly for your class. That's why I refer you to follow the recommendation in the 1st paragraph.