# Can you static_cast to derived class pointer in base class constructor, if the derived class is polymorphic?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, ubsan

Imagine following code with CRTP and polymorphism:

```
template <typename Derived>
class CRTP {
   public:
   // in real code, the result of this cast is saved in another class 
    CRTP() { static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

class MyClass : public CRTP<MyClass> {
    virtual void foo(){};
};

int main() { 
    MyClass m; 
}
```

After reading [Can you static_cast "this" to a derived class in a base class constructor then use the result later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172193/can-you-static-cast-this-to-a-derived-class-in-a-base-class-constructor-then-u) and standard ([[expr.static.cast]#12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#12), [[basic.life]#6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6), [[class.cdtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor)), I believe this is fine as long as the pointer and reference are not used aside from being saved to variable. However, UndefinedBehaviourSanitizer disagrees ([see it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6TKjxz3Wa)):

```
/app/example.cpp:4:14: runtime error: downcast of address 0x7ffdc5ba6df8 which does not point to an object of type 'MyClass'
0x7ffdc5ba6df8: note: object has invalid vptr
 fd 7f 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  83 00 04 1e ba 7f 00 00  80 8b 20 1e
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              invalid vptr
```

The error is gone if `Derived` is not polymorphic.

Is it just a false positive from UBSan or is there anything in the standard that changes the situation in case of polymorphic classes?

---

For reference, my real code looks more like this: https://godbolt.org/z/f9sePhv73. I store a reference to the `Derived` class in another class (not using in it constructor), and `MyClass` also inherits a mixin that makes it virtual, so it's not too simple to get rid of vptr.

Comment: Looks like a false positive. The code looks OK to me, for what it's worth. It's true that the vtable would only be initialized once `MyClass` constructor runs - but the cast doesn't rely on the vtable. I don't see why it should be relevant that `MyClass` is polymorphic; **[basic.life]** doesn't hinge on that.

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73172193/4641116

Comment: @Eljay won't say it's dup wrt to your link as the question is about a possible UBSan false positive. Yet I would have point, maybe, to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57294792/c-ubsan-produces-false-positives-with-derived-objects though it's a bit old

Comment: @Oersted Interesting, but I'm not sure if it's relevant - I can reproduce it on godbolt with single file, no `-fvisibility` flag used.

Comment: @Yksiarvinen And what happens if you simplify your example by removing ```Mixin``` and just declaring ```virtual foo()``` inside ```MyClass```? Possibly removing ```foo``` completely and giving ```MyClass``` a defaulted virtual dtor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ undefined behavior of a reference to a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77480934/c-undefined-behavior-of-a-reference-to-a-base-class)

Comment: @Oersted Indeed, it can be simplified to any cast (including C-style cast) from base class to `Derived` in CRTP, as long as `Derived` is polymorphic. Edited the question.

Comment: @Red.Wave Could you please explain why do you think it's a duplicate? There is no vector, no reference is invalidated by move. After minimising the example, it turned out I don't even need to store the reference anywhere, cast is enough to trigger UBSan.

Comment: \[expr.static.cast\]/12 requires `this` to point at a valid subobjcet of some other object, or get UB. During construction, the "other object" does not yet exist, so the condition doesn't hold => therefore UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Interesting, that would mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180292/7976805) is wrong. And now I see the question also references UBSan error (in comments), so I think it's valid duplicate after all.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The question was edited much later. The original post contained self-referenced objects. The new edit doesn't qualify as **minimum reproducible example** any more.

Comment: @Red.Wave - I'm not sure what you are referring  to. I only commented on the interpretation of a standard passage.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica compare the last edit time of comments and OP. The post primarily contained a UB. Now it is just a false claim after the edit. It is no more reproducible.

Comment: @Red.Wave I disagree that my edit made the question unreproducible. UndefinedBehaviourSanitizer still reports exactly the same issue (as can be seen on Godbolt). Either the cast itself is UB or not. The original question was *not* answered with your answer, because there was never any vector reallocation and no objects were invalidated.

Comment: It's unclear for me what the conclusion is: Is it UB to down-cast during construction or not (if I understand correctly [linked answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180292/7976805))

Comment: @Oersted It is well-defined (no UB) according to that answer. I will have to change my code anyway to silence UBSan, so I didn't want to bother anymore.